# How to find inheritance of modes?

Tags: major-mode, derived-mode

As an example, let's use `latex-mode`, that inherits from `tex-mode`, that inherits from `text-mode`. Is there a command, that would take as input `latex-mode` and give me parent and grand-parent? Or, other way around, is there a command that would take `text-mode` as input, and give me children and grand-children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property `derived-mode-parent` of a mode symbol gives you the parent mode it is derived from.

```lisp
(get 'latex-mode 'derived-mode-parent)
(get 'tex-mode 'derived-mode-parent)
```

This will give you a list of the hierarchy:

```lisp
(defun derived-modes (mode)
  "Return a list of the ancestor modes that MODE is derived from."
  (let ((modes   ())
        (parent  nil))
    (while (setq parent (get mode 'derived-mode-parent))
      (push parent modes)
      (setq mode parent))
    (setq modes  (nreverse modes))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a version based on recursion

```lisp
(defun my/derived-modes (mode)
  (interactive (list major-mode))
  (defun iter (mode)
    (and mode
         (cons mode
               (iter (get mode 'derived-mode-parent)))))
  (message "%s" (iter mode)))
```